# How does placing the statement to create an instance of Selenium WebDriver, inside/outside of a function affects find_elements_by_xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, multiprocessing, instance

Refer the following code:

```
def parse(height_id):
   driver2=webdriver.Firefox()
   driver2.get(height_id)
   block_details_web_element=driver2.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div')
   print (block_details_web_element)
   print(block_details_web_element.text)

   print(" --- BLOCK PARSED SUCCESSFULLY! ---\n")
   driver2.quit()

#the following parts are outside the function: 
p = Pool(4)
records = p.map(parse, height_list_on_each_page2) #height_list_on_each_page2 is a list of URLs.
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

(Eg. of a typical URL: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/000000000000000000028e473f1c95060a63100c9861525105b1f5ced81a7fa0 )

Now, this works fine, but takes huge time. So, I planned to put the statement `driver2=webdriver.Firefox()` outside the `parse` function, so that I don't re-create the instance of WebDriver each time I'm calling the function. [And I also removed the statement `driver2.quit()` from this function]. This is saving time, however, almost half of the times the print statment `print (block_details_web_element)` is returning `None` as output.

I doubt that the `find_elements_by_xpath` method is not working correctly. Is this because of multi-processing that I am using?

Any insight, why this is happening? Please suggest a solution.

EDIT : (this is the error)
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yvknbdg9wefuwy/selenium.jpeg?dl=0)

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath` won't return `None`, it will return the element or will throw `TimeoutException`. *Is this because of multi-processing that I am using?* this is probably the underline cause.

Comment: You misunderstood it. The statement [print (block_details_web_element)] is printing "none" in those cases, and the statement [ print(block_details_web_element.text) ] prints "None type element has no attribute text" in those cases.

Comment: If `print (block_details_web_element)` prints `None`, it means `block_details_web_element` is `None`, which means `find_element_by_xpath` returned `None`. This is not possible. It either something with the multi processing or the `None` come from another place.

Comment: See I'm getting this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yvknbdg9wefuwy/selenium.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: See the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yvknbdg9wefuwy/selenium.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Post errors in your question as text, not in links or images and not in the comments section.

Comment: Please show a way out. I'm very new to this and confused.

Comment: You have [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58908682/edit) button under the question tags, same line as your avatar.

Comment: i ycouldnt add text. there were too many errors in the editor. So, I added the link there